# UV Unwrap with correct rotation

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-coordinates

I'm wondering if there is a way to make unwrapping process faster and more pleasant.
So I have wood texture and simple model of the window, which has mostly vertical  faces. I want the lines of the texture to follow Z-axis on each surface. Smart UV project of simple unwrap rotates it kind of randomly. So are there any techniques or plugins which could help me? It would save lots of time!
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: selecting the offending areas should be easy using the L key, which considers seams disconnecting. Then in UV editor you can simply press R, 90, Enter, and pack islands.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady it kind of works, but after that the new islands are overlapped with the old. Should it be fixed manually? If I select everything and then "pack islands", it rotates the old ones randomly..

Comment: You can disable rotation in "pack islands"

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady It worked! =) Thank you so much! Could you write it as an answer please?